# hot to date indide parameter in xml

Tags: javascript, xml, datetime, date, insert

i made this code for inserting data to an system mail that know to work with xml file.
the problem is that i try to create some javascript code for getting the current date of day, and then put it inside the filed date, but without success.

i know hot create the date in javascript, my problem is in thx xml file, i mean 
how can i impplemt the date inside the filed date in the xml file.

the code(xml side):

123456

NOW
COMPLETE
ENGLISH

1274
liran
******

413
3280
86308
;
UNIX
email;dateofday
liroy7@gmail.com;(i want here to return the date from the javascript)

thanks,

Comment: Sorry, please reformulate your question It does not make any sense.

Comment: "NOW COMPLETE ENGLISH" - ironic. While it's understandable that English might not be your first language, it's expected that you'll try your best to express yourself clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand, but you can use getTime() on your Date objec to insert it into the XML file as milliseconds, and if you need to convert it back into a JavaScript object you can parse it directly.

```
function putInXmlFile(d) {
  writeToXML(d.getTime());
}

function getFromXmlFile() {
  var date = new Date(getFromXML());
}
```

It works because the JavaScript Date object can parse from the milliseconds from the epoch (which is returned by getTime).